# How to extracting individual dimensions from $node->content['dimensions'] in Drupal's Ubercart?

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

On my Ubercart node-product.tpl.php page, I am trying to extract the individual product dimensions (height, weight, length) from the more generic: `print $node->content['dimensions'] ['#value'];` which returns "Dimensions: 72in. × 42in. × 30in."

Using `var_dump(get_defined_vars());` I'm able to see that the dimensions are being outputted independently, but can't seem to get them to print. on the page. What is the proper way to call the dimensions individually?

Answer (score 0):

Can you dump the $node object? They are probably outside of the content array. Then you could do print $node->product->length, or whatever the properties are.